# If statement with multiple logical comparison

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax, compare

I need to check if $_POST['a'] is not empty AND is either '1' OR '2' so user cannot remove the a= or change the value from 1 or 2 to something else from the post path:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['a']) || !in_array($_POST['a'], array('1', '2'))) {
 echo 'error1';
} else if ($_POST['a'] == '1') {
 do something;
} else if ($_POST['a'] == '2') {
 do something;
} else {
 echo 'error2';
}
?>
```

Can anyone teach me how to do this in a correct way?

Many many thanks

Comment: It's more to type but it's more efficient to do `if (empty($_POST['a']) || ($_POST['a'] != 1 && $_POST['a'] != 2)) {` as opposed to the in_array

Comment: just tried and didn't work. I get error no matter a = 1, 2, 3, 4 or empty.

<?php
if(empty($_POST['a']) || ($_POST['a'] != 1 && $_POST['a'] != 2)){
echo 'error';
} else {
echo 'good';
}
?>

would that be a syntax issue?

Comment: It is a syntax issue. You are missing a `)` at the end of the first `if`. And this if why you need to use an IDE. I just used your code and made it prettier, never paid attention to syntax errors...

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited the post now and found out why it wasn't working coz I used $_POST instead of $_REQUEST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a switch instead:

```
switch ($_POST['a']):
case '':
    // empty
    echo 'error1';
    break;
case '1':
    // do something for 1
    break;
case '2':
    // do something for 2
    break;
default:
    // not empty but not 1 or 2
    echo 'error2';
endswitch;
```

Comment: This will throw a notice if $_POST['a'] is not set right? `case ''` isn't the same as `empty()`

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I come across the switch/case and it works well :p

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($_POST['a']) && $_POST['a'] == '1') { //Not empty AND is 1
 do something;
} else if (!empty($_POST['a']) && $_POST['a'] == '2') { //Not Empty AND is 2
 do something;
} else {
 echo 'error';
}
```

The first two will catch all "good" values, everything else will get the error. And no need for the top if in this case.

Comment: AND (&&)? I thought && means both true which mean if $_POST is '3' it will pass the first statement. Am I right?

Comment: it does mean if both true, and how would it pass the first statement 3  != 1

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: You have a syntax error. Missing a `)` at the end of the first `if`.

Two easy ways of doing this:

```
// first condition should be by itself as it's a terminal error
if(empty($_POST['a']) or !in_array($_POST['a'], array('1', '2'))) {
    echo 'error1';
    die; // or redirect here or just enfore a default on $_POST['a'] = 1; // let's say
}

// Second can be like this or embraced in the else of the first one (se ex.2)
if ($_POST['a'] == '1') {
    // do something;
} else if ($_POST['a'] == '2') {
    // do something;
}
```

or

```
// first condition should be by itself as it's a terminal error
if(empty($_POST['a']) or !in_array($_POST['a'], array('1', '2'))) {
    echo 'error1';
    // or redirect here or just enfore a default on $_POST['a'] = 1; // let's say
}else{ // Second is in the else here :)
    if ($_POST['a'] == '1') {
    // do something;
    } else if ($_POST['a'] == '2') {
        // do something;
    }
}
```

Your last `else` will not be reached as it will always end in the first `if` where you handle both emptiness and illegal value.